# Why is BINARY(16) performing worse than VARCHAR(36) for UUIDs?

Tags: java, mysql, database, optimization, jdbc

I tried to make a sort of benchmark test to show that using BINARY(16) over VARCHAR(36) for UUID columns in a MySQL database would bring speed improvements. According to my test code, however, I got confusing results. It only seemed to actually make things worse for large and small numbers of rows!

My code is a bit messy, but it makes a database with two tables that differ only in the BINARY/VARCHAR column, populates them with a certain number of rows, and then compares how long it takes to query both of them in some random order (the order is the same for both of them).

https://gist.github.com/MarkLalor/c2f7a0861eb29d87a56715aa33c9a3e8

The results with a MySQL server on localhost (note it's percentage decrease, so positive numbers are the "good" ones):

[image]

The X axis is the number of rows that were used for that test. Each row number is the average of 10 tests (one test is -> create db/tables/fill with numbers/shuffle/query/delete db)

I thought that at small and big numbers, the difference would be small, but I didn't think it would bring constant speed *reductions!* At first I thought it was just because of the time it takes to query the database, but I added the average of 10 feature to eliminate this.

Comment: What do you mean by "shuffle"? Also, many would consider even your "large" test rather small; and BINARY(**16**) vs VARCHAR(**36**) suggests you might be using very different uuid values.

Comment: That data is so inconsistent I think you're fighting against statistical noise here. In any case, using a `BINARY` column for performance reasons, shaving all of 20 bytes off of a row, is not really going to matter much until you're dealing with billions of rows. Have you properly tuned your InnoDB engine?

Comment: It may be worth ruling out any artifact that may be introduced by the Java code (e.g. `.getUUID().toString()` vs. `.getBytes()`). I would precompute the two lists of parameters. Also notice that the difference fades away above 20k rows, where performance only begins to be meaningful (for smaller tables, the query is likely to last microseconds, then the time spent in transferring and parsing the results is non negligible)

Comment: @Uueerdo the shuffle is Collections.shuffle for the List of TestRow objects. VARCHAR(36) holds a value like "e3f0eb43-36b5-42a3-9d27-bb82eb025c7f" whereas BINARY(16) is the binary form of the same information.

Comment: @tadman I agree :( I assumed it would help a lot with lookup times. I am by all means a database amateur, I've never even heard of InnoDB, unfortunately (good to start learning, time to research!)

Comment: @RandomSeed I totally forgot about the toString()! I did precompute the byte arrays. Which means that if I precompute the Strings, that the statistics will only favor the opposite of what I'm expecting even more.

Comment: InnoDB is the recommended engine for MySQL and offers a lot of [knobs and dials to adjust performance](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-innodb.html). You'll probably have more luck adjusting settings than tinkering with column types that are basically the same size. When asking performance related questions it's often important to have the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` description in your question so people can try to reproduce your results or make improvements to it.

Comment: Sorry, what were you expecting? VARCHAR is expected to be slower than BINARY. Also you should compare VARCHAR vs. VARBINARY, the VAR bit comes at a price.

Comment: @RandomSeed well no the confusing part is that BINARY seems to be slower than VARCHAR (at small numbers, I would expect it to at least be the same).

Comment: @tadman This is very interesting, it's very helpful that you mentioned it. And thanks for the future advice. I'm probably a bit ahead of my skis with things here but it's mostly for learning purposes.

Comment: Another thing you might want to look at is the order of operations you are performing; you might try alternating which table gets queried first and/or query both in the same loop.

Comment: Error:  `statement.setBytes(1, rows.get(i).getBytes());` does not generate a UUID.

Comment: Incomplete:  Increase the row count past the point where the table cannot fit in the buffer_pool.